# When is Contract instance actually finished running?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pab, pab, offchain

I'm trying to write tests for my smart contracts.
I want to test if my contract has finished running by using this predicate:

```
-- | A 'TracePredicate' checking that the wallet's contract instance finished
--   without errors.
assertDone
    :: forall contract w s e a.
    ( Monoid w
    , IsContract contract
    )
    => contract w s e a
    -> ContractInstanceTag
    -> (a -> Bool)
    -> String
    -> TracePredicate
assertDone contract inst pr = assertOutcome contract inst (\case { Done a -> pr a; _ -> False})
```

But i'm getting this at the beginning of the test:

```
    Outcome of Wallet W872c:
      False
    Failed 'asserting contract is done'
    Test failed.
    Emulator log:
    [INFO] Slot 0: TxnValidate a43ac4a162e963b6ccdbece83f96cabefd53df73c8de6b242aedbeb2ca8b8f80
    [INFO] Slot 1: 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000 {Wallet W872c}:
```

and at the end of the test:

```
    [INFO] Slot 5: 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000001 {Wallet W872c}:
                     Contract log: String "End of contract"
    [INFO] Slot 5: 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000001 {Wallet W872c}:
                     Contract instance stopped (no errors)
      src/Plutus/Contract/Test.hs:270:
      Check if contract is done
    
    Use -p '/Check if contract is done/' to rerun this test only.

1 out of 2 tests failed (0.19s)
Test suite myTests: FAIL
```

I have put: `logInfo @String "End of contract"` at the end of my contract so we can clearly see that all of my statements written in my Contract instance goes trough.

I was expecting `assertDone` to return me **True**, since no error was thrown, but I still got a **False**.

So the question is, why my contract is not producing **Done** output and is still waiting for input?

```
data Outcome e a =
    Done a
    -- ^ The contract finished without errors and produced a result
    | NotDone
    -- ^ The contract is waiting for more input.
    | Failed e
    -- ^ The contract failed with an error.
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```